# JBAS015986 Host Controller shutdown has been requested via an OS signal

Tags: java, server, jboss6.x

We are using JBoss EAP-6.1 for our project. But the server is getting stopped by itself after sometime due to **JBAS015986 Host Controller shutdown has been requested via an OS signal error**. Can somebody please help me resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding -Xrs JVM option. For more details see https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MysteriousShutdowns

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)